# Experiementing with regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Given the string: `"hello \\n world"` how would I use replace to then transform that into: `"hello \\\n world"`

would it be `.replace(/\\/g, /\\\\\\/)`?

Keep in mind I know this is not valid. But I wanted to see if this could be done. And I am new to regex.

Comment: Did you try it? Note: The second argument to `replace` should not be a regular expression. See the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace .

Comment: I did but it did nothing. What is the correct answer?

Comment: `"hello \\n world".replace(/\\/g, '\\\\\\')` -> `"hello \\\n world"`

Comment: `"hello \\\n world"` is a ``\`` followed by a line break. Is that really what you want or do you want the string to literally contain `\\\n` (three backslashes and an "n").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this:**

```
    var a = "hello \\n world";

    var b = a.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\\\");

alert(b);
```

[DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/Luu00q07/)

Comment: Question: Why is it not replacing each instance of \ with \\\ using this regex?

Comment: @ashutosh It is. \\ is one character. It's \ escaped. So the string is a literal \ followed by an n

Comment: @MrBurger I know \\ is one charater. What I am asking is the string "hello \\n world" has two literal backslashes, why isn't the regex replacing each \ with \\\ and making it "hello \\\\\\n world"?

Comment: for me I get: `\\\\\\n`

Comment: Show your code @KyleAdams. I just figured, this answer should be correct.

Comment: @ashutosh It only has one literal backslash? If you type the above code in the javascript console and print `a` it will only show one backslash.