# 6 slashes not being escaped ... Whats going on

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Consider the following code:

```
  console.log(description);
  var description = description.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\\\");
  console.log(description);
```

Consider the following image:

[image]

First one has two `\\`'s the second has 6. Why is the string not being escaped? it should be `\\\` not `\\\\\\`

Comment: And i suppose the \ in the regex is not escaped? (If it is, one \ is replaced by three \\)

Comment: well then how do I make it so that there are three not 6

Comment: Try with \\\\ in the regex?

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, you should have clarified your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33833231/experiementing-with-regex-javascript). The way you presented the information was ambiguous. It wasn't clear whether the string value was `hello \\n world` or `hello \n world`. People asked you questions in the comments but you didn't really answer.

Comment: Try `var description = description.replace(/\\+/g, "\\\\\\");`. This will replace any 1 or more ``\``s to 3 backslashes.

Comment: What is expected resulting string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex `/\\/g` matches one slash (`\`), and since you replace each slash with three slashes, you get six slashes.

If you want to replace two slashes with three slashes, use `/\\\\/g` regex, like this:

```
console.log(description);
description = description.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\\\\\");
console.log(description);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're telling it to replace a single slash (Regex: `/\\/` = `\`) with 3 slashes `"\\\\\\"` = `\\\`.

So when it sees a literal `\\n` it replaces each of the two slashes with 3 slashes each, totalling 6 slashes.

**You want 2 slashes replaced by 3 slashes?**

Use `/\\\\/` for your regex like so:

```
description.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\\\\\");
```

Reason being each double-slash represents a single slash in the compiled regex since backslash is an escape character in a regex.

Comment: this doesn't help me, whats the correct solution? its imformative but not a solution

Comment: You want 2 slashes replaced by 3 slashes? Use `/\\\\/` for your regex

Comment: Reason being each double-slash represents a single slash in the compiled regex since backslash is an escape character in a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You wrongly assume that the 6 slashes in the result text are produced by one match and replace. They are the result of two separate replaces.
This is because your regular expression looks for one slash only, not two.

Although you escaped the backslashes in the second argument, you did not do so in the first.

If your goal is to replace two backslashes with three, then also escape the backslashes in the regular expression (first argument):

```
var description = description.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\\\\\");
```

Comment: You get those six because you have in your image two consecutive backslashes, and each of them is **separately** found by your reg ex. That is why you get the first one replace by 3 and the second one replaced by 3 = 6. This correction will replace the original 2 in one go, and put 3. Don't think that your code produced 6 in one go, it did so in two.

Comment: @KyleAdams: The difference is in the regular expression, not the replacement value.